# LibVLC Android stream from minimal HTTP server

Tags: java, android, http, vlc, libvlc

I am trying to write an application similar to the well-known Popcorn Time - an app which lets you watch movies over torrents. It basically uses NanoHTTPD as a bridge between the LibVLC player and the torrent library to be able to stream it. I use this exact same HTTP library.

The problem I have is that, even though using chrome's built-in MP4 viewer works fine, I cannot play the video from VLC. I did notice that it sends an 'Icy-Metadata: 1' header in the HTTP request which Chrome doesn't but little is documentated on that so I'm not sure if that's the problem here.

The desktop version of VLC player does not play it either. It stands there, requesting the same over and over again without displaying my video. What could I be missing?

It may be worth noting that nginx serves it properly, but it seems like nginx doesn't even reply with any kind of http header response. Just data.